# How can I split a HTML string at center of tags in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a section of HTML into an array of 2 values to wrap around a template. I am trying to avoid using a placeholder but wondered if there was some way of performing something similar to the jQuery `wrap()` function.

So this is the code that I want to wrap:

```
<img src="/resources/img/photo.png">
```

This is the portion of HTML that I wish to wrap the image above:

```
<div class="container"><div class="col-md-6"></div></div>
```

So that the end result will be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="/resources/img/photo.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way that I can currently think of doing it is with a placeholder like so but would like to not have to use this method:

```
<div class="container"><div class="col-md-6">[REPLACE_ME]</div></div>
```

Any help you can give me on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: jQuery wrap has context. You select the DOM to be wrapped. I don't understand what the context is here. Are these PHP files, string variables or client side HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you pretty much have to use a placeholder if you're going to try to do this using just string manipulation. Otherwise, PHP won't really know where to put the contents within the wrapper. The `[REPLACE_ME]` could be done using `%s` in a format string for `printf` or `sprintf`.

```
$contents = '<img src="/resources/img/photo.png">';

$wrapper = '<div class="container"><div class="col-md-6">%s</div></div>';
//                                            [REPLACE_ME]^

$result = sprintf($wrapper, $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
<?php
    $img = '<img src="/resources/img/photo.png">';    
    echo '<div class="container"><div class="col-md-6">'.$img.'</div></div>';
```

In `PHP`, if you want something to show up on a page, you need to use `echo`. You then can concatenate a string using `.`.